# react-select library dependencies in .net core

Tags: select, undefined, libraries, react-select, reactjs.net

I am new to react
I am using react libraries by including them in my _Layout.cshtml
So i am not able to use the multi select react dropdown from the react-select library
I added some dependencies for react-select but i still got the error “uncaught referenceerror : Select is not defined “
If anyone can help

[screeshot of my code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TojpX.jpg)

in the _layout page:

```
<!-- React Libraries -->
<script src="~/js/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="~/js/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="~/js/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/emotion.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/memoize-one.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/react-input-autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/react-transition-group.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/react-select.js"></script>
```

in js file :

```
<div className="col-lg-6">
                    <label className="font-weight-bold text-dark col-form-label form-control-label text-2">
                        Industries you are interested in </label>
                    <Select id="ddlIndustry" value={industry || ''} className="form-control multi-select" isMulti
                        onChange={e => mutipleSelect(e.target.value)} multiple>

                        <option value="-1">-- Select Industry you are intrested in --</option>
                        {industries.map(industry => (
                            <option value={industry['businessSectorId']} key={industry['businessSectorId']}>
                                {industry['name']}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </Select>
                </div>
```

Remark i am using  the tag select with capital s
Because i read that i should use the capital s not the small s